# If Java doesn't support operator overloading, then how Integer class could support "++"?

Tags: java, class, operator-overloading, wrapper

E.g, we can:

```
Integer i = 2;
++i;
// now i = 3
```

We know that Integer is a raw wrapper type that's immutable like string, so `++i` actually will construct a new Integer object, right? So `++i` could be equal to `i = Integer.valueOf(i.intValue() + 1)`

Question:

If java doesn't support operator overloading of `++` like C++ language, then how "++i" is compiled and run? Is it just a form of syntax sugar?

Comment: It is syntactic sugar.  The `Integer` is being unboxed to a primitive `int`, and then the `++` is applied that that, with the result being stored again in an `Integer`.

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean by "support operator overloading".  Clearly Java "has operators", but can they be overloaded?

Comment: the compiler (OpenJDK 18) *translates* it to byte code representing `Integer.valueOf(i.intValue() + 1)`, exactly as you posted

Comment: Of course, Java *has* overloaded operators. Most notably, `+` works on integers, floating point values, and even strings. What Java doesn’t support, is adding custom overloads. Applying operators on wrapper types, is a distraction, as unwrapping and rewrapping isn’t overloading at all, however, as said at the beginning, overloaded operators exists.